# How to show that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is finitely dimensional?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $M, N$ be right $A$-modules and $A$ a ring over a field $K$. If $\dim_KM$ and $\dim_KN$ are finite, how to show that $\dim_K \operatorname{Hom}_A(M, N)$ is finite? I think that $\dim_K \operatorname{Hom}_K(M, N) = \dim_KM \dim_KN$.

In linear algebra, the set of all linear transformations from a vector space $M$ ($\dim = m$) to a vector space $N$ ($\dim = n$) is the set of all $m\times n$ matrices. So the dimension of the algebra of all linear transformations from $M$ to $N$ is $mn$. But I don't know the situation here.

What is the relation between $\dim_K \operatorname{Hom}_A(M, N)$ and $\dim_KM \dim_KN$?  Thank you very much.

Comment: A hom is uniquely given by its values on a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Hom_A(M, N) \subset Hom_K(M, N)$, so 
$dim_A Hom_A(M, N) \le dim_K Hom_K(M, N) = dim_KM dim_KN$.

As to last question, consider, for example, non-isomorphic simple modules $M,N$. Then $dim_K Hom_A(M, N)=0$, but $Hom_K(M,N) > 0$.